# org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 Not Found

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

In my Spring Boot application I am trying to implement login with basic Spring Security.

```
public Response verifyLogin( String username, String password ) throws Exception
{
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
    HttpEntity<Login> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>( new Login( username, password ), headers );
    ResponseEntity<Response<UserDetail>> response = restTemplate.exchange( getEndpoint( ConfigurationConstants.LOGIN_URL ), HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, new ParameterizedTypeReference<Response<UserDetail>>()
    {
    } );
    return response.getBody();
}
```

Above **restTemplate.exchange** method throws below exception.

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 Not Found
at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:78) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:700) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:653) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:613) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:559) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at it.codegen.tbx.pbs.web.service.LoginService.verifyLogin(LoginService.java:60) ~[classes/:na]
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: Check with both server endpoint

Comment: Server endpoint works fine. I think the issue is the way I am calling it.

Comment: what is a value for _getEndpoint( ConfigurationConstants.LOGIN_URL )_?

Comment: hitting URL is not same as in the controller